# How do I preserve conditional attributes on buttons after a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My problem is this:

I'm creating a gridview that contains buttons. In these buttons, certain default text is displayed.

At the very bottom of the grid, there is a unique button that will create an additional row onclick.

Now, after I create my initial rows on the first page load, and all of the default button attributes are present, I am then able to select a value from a dropdown list that changes the text of the button in the next cell over.

But when I click to add a new row, that button text is reverted back to the default.

The selected value of the dropdown list does not change however.

I'm referencing this tutorial:

http://snipplr.com/view/72801/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-dropdownlists-in-aspnet/

But have adjusted the code to include a dynamic button

```
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;
                //add new row to DataTable
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    //extract the DropDownList Selected Items
                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                    // Update the DataRow with the DDL Selected Items
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"] = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"] = ddl2.SelectedItem.Text;

                }

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }


    protected void Change_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((DropDownList)sender).NamingContainer;
        int index = row.RowIndex;
        Button btn = (Button)Gridview1.Rows[index].Cells[3].FindControl("btn");
        btn.Text = "HELLO";
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
    }
```

---

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Change_Button">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Default">
            </asp:Button>                   
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Can anybody explain how I'm able to maintain the desired text, or any attribute for that matter, on the postback?

This is strictly for my own education. I'm trying to learn more about preserving the page's state when I move between webforms.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but for the most common web hosting scenarios, the most constrained resource is _memory_. Using the ViewState to keep your grid puts the entire dataset into memory for the life of the page session. It's more typical to try to do as much of this as possible on the client via javascript, and avoid doing postbacks at all as much as possible, where you only communicate the changes to the server once when the user is ready to move to a new page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually trying to do this without Javascript. I want to really understand how the Viewstate and Session operate before I start optimizing it. But I do agree with what you're saying. This should be handled on the client side.